# When to close restored transactions the user doesn't download

Tags: ios, storekit

When restoring transactions for non-consumable Apple hosted content, how do you determine when to close the transactions that the user decides not to download at that moment?

Apple suggests this but doesn't explain how:

> If your app uses the app receipt and has Apple-hosted content, let the user select which products to restore before starting the restoration process. During restoration, re-download the user-selected content and finish any other transactions immediately.

They seem to imply that you are forcing the user to decide if they would like to download or not download every single item, immediately.

I'd like to instead change the download button to an optional "restore" state that can be pressed whenever the user would like, such as this:
(Here's our app with the download button for each downloadable product in a "restore" state.)

[image: Here's our app with the download button for each downloadable product in a "restore" state.]

The problem with this implementation is that you aren't closing out the other transactions that the user doesn't want to download.

I tried closing the transactions on the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, but the close transaction requests weren't being sent out to Apple.

Is this implementation possible? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I stated:

> "I tried closing the transactions on the applicationDidEnterBackground method, but the close transaction requests weren't being sent out to Apple."

But that was incorrect. You can close all your open transactions in the App Delegate function, `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

The following code will close all your restored transactions so your user isn't prompted to login with their Apple ID next time they open your app.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    for transaction in SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().transactions {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }
}
```